# How to retrieve all the record from a parent table that have association with it child

Tags: entity-framework

I have a table named `Organization` & `Organization_Details`. But how I can retrieve all the organization records that have association with the Organization_detials.

I am trying to write something such as :-

```
Public Organization getallorg ()
{
Entities.Organization.any(a=>a.OrganizationDetials)//…….
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
  Entities.Organization.where(a=>a.OrganizationDetials!=null &&  
                                  a.OrganizationDetials.count()>0 )
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i think doing so will not scale well , will it be better to join the two entities ? I wanted to stay away of joining entities . what do u think?

Comment: May be this will more efective. I'm not 100% sure. But the most salable will be writing a stored procedure. :)  `where(a=>a.OrganizationDetials!=null &&  
                                  a.OrganizationDetials.Any() )`